# A construction consisting of 2 clauses where the first one expresses a vague negation of what's more precisely formulated in the following clause?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> **It wasn't like** my mother was angry, **but** she was still unhappy.
>
> **It wasn't that** my mother was angry, **but** she was still unhappy.
>
> My mother **wasn't exactly** angry, **but** she was still unhappy.

In general, I'm trying to find an English construction (if there is one) that consists of two clauses where the first clause has an indefinite (or vague?) negation of what is more precisely formulated in the following clause.

Are the above ones good? Which is better for my purpose? Are there any other?

Comment: #1 is more "sloppily slangy" than the other two, but they're all reasonably natural utterances - it's just a stylistic choice which you decide to use. Is there any reason for you apparently randomly discarding the word ***still*** and switching from ***mom*** to ***mother*** after the first version? That certainly doesn't help the "unambiguous answerability"  of the question.

Comment: No important reason at all. I just let myself add a little variation in the parts that are not important for my question. I've made them more alike now.

Comment: One common construction is "not so much [adjective] as [another adjective]." This one doesn't work for polar opposites ("He was not so much happy as sad"), but works well in your example ("She as not so much angry as unhappy"). Can also be rearranged "She was not angry so much as unhappy." This construction works well when the first adjective is *partly* true, but the second one is *more* relevant.

Comment: Haha - I can see why you might think it's actually potentially *useful* to include irrelevant variations to those parts of the text you're *not* directly concerned with. Certainly if I as a native speaker wanted to give a few examples of some usage, that could be a helpful technique. But when *asking* a question here, I'm sure it's usually better that the *only* variation should specifically be the text being queried.

Comment: (I also thought of a construction that does the opposite of what you asked, in which the first clause says something explicitly that is understood to be true, even though it is negated, and the second clause hints vaguely at details: "I'm not saying that [exactly what you mean to say], but [details that suggest that conclusion]." As Kanye West puts it: "I ain't saying she's a gold digger / but she ain't dating no broke ____s.")

Comment: I just searched Google Books for the three separately quotated strings [**"wasn't angry" "but" "exactly happy".**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wasn%27t+angry%22+%22but%22+%22exactly+happy%22)  The third result was *She wasn't exactly happy, but she wasn't angry either*, and the fourth result was *She wasn't angry. But she wasn't exactly happy either*. On the other hand, searching for the ever-so-slightly different [**"wasn't happy" "but" "exactly angry"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22exactly+angry%22+%22but%22+%22wasn%27t+happy%22) returned *no relevant examples*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you mean to say that it's a bad phrasing and writers avoid it?

Comment: I have no idea why it just so happens that many writers have contrasted not being exactly happy with not being angry either, whereas no-one ever seems to have contrasted not being exactly angry with not being happy either. Logically, it's not obvious to me that either version should be considered "better" than the other - in fact, I'm far from convinced it's even possible to claim they have different meanings / allusions. To a first approximation, they should be considered semantically identical, but only one version seems to get used (but in *both* sequences, as I first pointed out).

Comment: ...and it's all the more bizarre because I've just discovered that [***wasn't exactly happy*** is far more common than ***wasn't exactly angry***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wasn%27t+exactly+angry%2Cwasn%27t+exactly+happy&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) (the difference looks far too extreme to be dismissed as a meaningless statistical blip). And yet when contrasting "neither exactly one nor the other", in the construction we're looking at here, we always attach ***exactly*** to the adjective we're ***least*** likely to use in more general contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe it's just simply that people say "wasn't exactly angry" far more seldom than they say "wasn't exactly happy. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my previous comment, *and backed up with the usage chart*. The point is I've no idea *why* such a marked preference should exist. and it was you who asked me whether there might be some concept of "bad phrasing" involved, but I'm sure that's not it.

Comment: This is not a question about English, it's a game. Vote to close.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Anger is an acute, easily identified state. Happiness is vague and more chronic. So happiness seems more likely not to be exact.